# How show to a user a "consuming information" like this picture?

Tags: html, charts, bootstrap-4, frontend, show

Sorry, but I can't explain better than showing this picture

[Consuming Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ0d5.jpg)

Is there a library/bootstrap/code already implemented that can show information like this picture? I can't even name it... it is not a pie chart, I don't know how to name this, but I think it must be already implemented somewhere.

I need to show a number like this image, wherever the user consume this value, it should decrease in this "circular chart".

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I have no idea what this image is trying to show as it is pretty low-res and has no context. Could you attempt to explain it a little further? Why is there a number surrounded by a blue circle?

Comment: Minimalist Chart!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a 'gauge' is the best name for something like this, you can create one using the library:

http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/

And the following code

```
var opts = {
   angle: 0.35, // The span of the gauge arc
   lineWidth: 0.1, // The line thickness
   radiusScale: 1, // Relative radius
   pointer: {
       length: 0.6, // // Relative to gauge radius
       strokeWidth: 0.035, // The thickness
       color: '#000000' // Fill color
   },
   limitMax: false,     // If false, max value increases automatically if value > maxValue
   limitMin: false,     // If true, the min value of the gauge will be fixed
   colorStart: '#6F6EA0',   // Colors
   colorStop: '#C0C0DB',    // just experiment with them
   strokeColor: '#EEEEEE',  // to see which ones work best for you
   generateGradient: true,
   highDpiSupport: true,     // High resolution support

};

var target = document.getElementById('graph'); // your canvas element
var gauge = new Donut(target).setOptions(opts); // create sexy gauge!
gauge.maxValue = 3000; // set max gauge value
gauge.setMinValue(0);  // Prefer setter over gauge.minValue = 0
gauge.animationSpeed = 32; // set animation speed (32 is default value)
gauge.set(1250); // set actual value
```

Don't forget to include the script in your page and add an element with an ID of 'graph' to your page, e.g.

```
<div id="graph"></div>
```